# Using regex to determine all postfixes of a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a simple way of matching a string and all it's post-fixes using a regex expression. For example I have the string "Rainforest". Is there a simplified regex expression that matches all of the following:

```
R$
Ra$
Rai$
Rain$
Rainf$
Rainfo$
Rainfor$
Rainfore$
Rainfores$
Rainforest$
```

I have found that I can use this as a method of finding all the post-fixes.

```
\b(R|Ra|Rai|Rain|Rainf|Rainfo|Rainfor|Rainfore|Rainfores|Rainforest)\b
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
\b(?:Ra?i?n?f?o?r?e?s?t?)\b
```

would match those, but it would also match some other strings such as `Ran`, if that'd be OK.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KQEQcu/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/KQEQcu/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Another option would be nested groups:

```
\bR(a(i(n(f(o(r(e(s(t)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KF5fII/1/)